# SQL Server Management Studio restoring a backed up table

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I am attempting to restore a table that is backed up through SQL Server Management Studio. So I right click on the database and hit tasks then restore, and that brings up this box:

[image]

However, this will restore the entire jobs database when I only need to restore one of the 7 tables within this database. How to I do this?

The table I need to restore was last right about a week ago, and all the other tables in the database were added to today and cant afford to be reverted to their week old versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not restore just a few tables without restoring the entire database. You have two things you can do:

1. Restore the whole database somewhere else and then copy the 7 tables in question into your database
2. Put those 7 tables into a separate filegroup and then backup and restore just that filegroup. Also it has to be a secondary filegroup since in order to restore primary filegroup you still need to restore the whole database

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is temporarily restore the database backup to the new database on the same server. Then, you can do with it whatever you want and drop it afterwards.

So, if I were in your place, I would do the following:

1. Restore the database to a new database on server
2. Restore tables from this new database. I suppose you just have to copy the data, so you have the options to a) delete from target and insert from source to target, or b) to perform a merge
3. Drop this new database